# Twitter JSON losing quotes around properties?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, arrays, json

Here's part of my JSON:

```
  [
  UserJSONImpl{
    id=1489761876,
    name='CharlesPerin',
    screenName='charles_perin',
    location='Paris,
    France',
    description='PhdStudentatINRIA-Univ.Paris-Sud-CNRS-LIMSI#infovis#dataviz#hci',
    isContributorsEnabled=false,
    profileImageUrl='http: //a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3766400220/bbced44afe69e60eb30e00f593a2f3b5_normal.jpeg',
    profileImageUrlHttps='https: //si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3766400220/bbced44afe69e60eb30e00f593a2f3b5_normal.jpeg',
    url='http: //t.co/eYSy04EzEk',
    isProtected=false,
    },
    UserJSONImpl{
        id=19671465,
        name='KevinQuealy',
        screenName='KevinQ',
        location='NewYork,
        NY',
        description='AgraphicseditorattheNewYorkTimes.AdjunctatNYU#SHERP.ReturnedPeaceCorpsvolunteer.Bald,
        Minnesotan,
        talkstoomuch.',
        isContributorsEnabled=false,
        profileImageUrl='http: //a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2213326305/image_normal.jpg',
        profileImageUrlHttps='https: //si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2213326305/image_normal.jpg',
        url='http: //t.co/vb0j99kE3N',
        isProtected=false,
        ...(cont)
```

This was returned directly from a call to twitter4j's lookupUsers:

```
long[] hundredIDs = new long[100];
  org.json.JSONArray users = new org.json.JSONArray();
  for(int a = 0; a < (int)((double)friendArray.length()/100 +1); a++)
  {   

      for(int j = 100*a; j < 100*(a+1); j++)
      {
        hundredIDs[j-100*a] = Long.parseLong(friendArray.getString(j)); 
      }
      users = new org.json.JSONArray(twitter.lookupUsers(hundredIDs)); //lookup users in batches of 100


    for(int k = 0; k < users.length(); k++)
    {
      org.json.JSONObject user = users.getJSONObject(k);
      if(Long.parseLong(user.getString("followers_count")) >= 500)
      {
        String id = user.getString("id"); //get id for each JSONObject
        friendArrayFiltered.add(id); //store ids in another array
      }
    }
```

For some reason, the JSON returned by my code doesn't have the standard quotes around the properties ("id"= ...., rather than id =...). It doesn't seem to be a problem of the Twitter API itself since their examples are in the correct format: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup.
Does anyone know what the problem is?

Also, not sure if this is a consequence but when I attempt to access individual elements of the JSONArray (like JSONArray[0]), an error is returned saying JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject. Is this linked to the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not JSON, it's actually generated by the [`UserJSONImpl#toString()`](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-core/src/main/java/twitter4j/internal/json/UserJSONImpl.java#L660-698) method which is providing a textual representation for each of the `User` objects returned by the `lookupUsers` invocation.

As for your second problem, you cannot use the `[]` operator on `Object` types in Java so I'm a little unclear what you mean without further information.

***ASIDE***

I'm not sure why you are wrapping twitter4j objects in `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` objects - of course you may have a good reason for doing this that's not apparent in the question - but you can simply use the methods directly on the returned objects to get the information you need, for example:

```
final List<User> users = twitter.lookupUsers(hundredIDs);
for (User user : users) {
    final int followersCount = user.getFollowersCount();
    if (followersCount > 500) { 
        ... etc...
```

Check out the [`User` JavaDocs](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/User.html) and wider [documentation](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/index.html) for the project.